# Nuget pack for multiple frameworks

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-standard

I am trying to make nuget package targeting multiple frameworks. But it doesn't work.
csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
   <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
   <NuGetPackageImportStamp />
 </PropertyGroup>
```

running command:

```
C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\.nuget\nuget pack "C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\TestPackaging\TestPackaging.csproj"
```

It gives me error:

Error NU5012: Unable to find 'bin\Debug\TestPackaging\bin\Debug\'. Make sure the project has been built.

If I change config to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
   <NuGetPackageImportStamp />
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

everythings works fine. What am I missing? Changing location where I am running it from makes no difference.

EDIT:
running command

```
C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\.nuget\nuget pack "C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\TestPackaging\TestPackaging.csproj" -build
```

gives different error:

```
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.50
Packing files from 
'C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\TestPackaging\bin\Debug\TestPackaging\bin\Debug'.
Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Repos\Random\TestStuff\TestPackaging\bin\Debug\TestPackaging\bin\Debug'.
```

same with nuspec file

Comment: I don't think net4.5 implements .net standard 2. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard ). You are also packing it with debug configuration. So it will gather the debug stuff in the nuget. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: package is compatible with 4.5.2 and standard 2.0, so building that into those two things shouldn't be an issue. I am not trying to consume here net standard in 4.5.2

Comment: Have you tried using build? nuget pack "project.csproj" -build

Comment: Hi! Just throwing my two cent: if there isn't any .NetFramework specific code inside the project, just target .netstandard20 and you should be fine as long as in the consuming project, you are using package references

Comment: Main issue that I am trying to solve is our core library has a bit of C# classes that we would want to use everywhere. But entire set of consumers for that library ranges from 4.5.2, to .NET Core. And there are some code with generics that is not supported below 2.0 standard. So I can't upgrade it to 4.5.2 at the same time I can't make it net standard 1.3. If I target them both the output spits two DLL's that I could add to nuget. What I don't understand how can I package them with nuget. I tried doing it with MSBuild and it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

nuget.exe doesn't support packing PackageReference projects, and SDK projects are always PackageReference.

You should pack using either `dotnet pack` or `msbuild -t:pack`

Comment: so why does it work where I change it to "<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>"?

Comment: It appears to work when you target a single TFM, because the single-TFM SDK project is similar enough to an "old style" project that `nuget pack` was designed for, so `nuget pack`'s assumptions and conventions happen to work (old style csprojs could never multi-target, you needed multiple csprojs). But PackageReferences don't get added as NuGet dependencies, which is another example of something that `nuget pack` doesn't support.

Comment: Since I'm new to the team, I decided to do a little digging. The failure ultimately is because [this block of code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/c8dc95a1c1b2bc16cb7ae7f8b50d44a471911428/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands/ProjectFactory.cs#L470-L480) is trying to find where the compiler output is, but `TargetPath` is only set when there's a single TFM (either when the project has a single TFM, or when the SDK is compiling one of the TFMs in a multi-TFM project). This returns null when evaluating, but not building, a multi-tfm project.

Comment: [Getting the TFM](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/c8dc95a1c1b2bc16cb7ae7f8b50d44a471911428/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands/ProjectFactory.cs#L129) also returns null, but it's not quite as catastrophic, since I think NuGet only uses it to nest dependencies. Without a TFM, NuGet I think just adds the dependencies to all TFMs in the nuspec. Anyway, point is that nuget.exe was never designed/updated for multi-tfm projects. There was work to make NuGet work though MSBuild targets, so going forward you should use msbuild or dotnet cli

Answer (score 2):

To target Multiple frameworks with nupsec xml attributes in the csproj SDK style file. Add this TargetFrameworks(with an 's'), back in the csproj:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net462;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

[Edit the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework#edit-the-manifest), add these lines in the ProjectGroup that defined TargetFrameworks:

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\net462\TestPackaging.dll" target="lib\net452\TestPackaging.dll" />
  <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.0\TestPackaging.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\TestPackaging.dll" />
</files>
```

Build the project, and the dll's go into their respective directories, the nuget get's built with source files for both target frameworks.